# Can LSF be configured to restrict access to a queue based on executable or by passing a token

Tags: lsf

I'm a casual and mostly inexperienced LSF user, so please bear with...

I develop software in a corporate setting that submits jobs to LSF for processing.  We have a set of machines that we want to use for a specific application but not open up to the public at large for any other usage.  There is something in place now that allowsa few specific users access to use the machines.  But we also want any user to use them IF they are running a certain application (a shell script that runs a perl script in this case).

I suppose registering the application(s) would be one approach.  Another might be to pass a secret/encrypted token or key.  Or maybe there are other mechanisms for this.

Is there an LSF based solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of LSF features that can help here.  A queue or application profile can have dedicated hosts, and users (the HOSTS and USERS parameters).

Queues can have a [job starter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/job_starters_about.html) to check and reject invalid job commands.

Comment: "job starter" looks intriguing.  I don't think HOSTS and USERS alone will work in this case because we want to permit/reject use of the queue based on the tool that's submitting the job.  But if we pass too id info along with the command, maybe code in job starter would sense that and act on it.

Thanks Michael !